# Why negative of a long int gives overflow?

Tags: c, long-integer, integer-overflow

When I write following, it gives no compilation warning/error.

```
  long universe_of_defects = 4294967295L;
```

But when I negate the long int, it gives compilation warning.

```
  long universe_of_defects = -4294967295L;

 warning: overflow in conversion from 'long long int' to 'long int' changes value from '-4294967295' to '1' [-Woverflow]
```

Why?

In addition, following is the least value of the long int, it is not giving warning while compilation.
long universe_of_defects = -2147483648L;

As per documentations, 32 bits can hold either from 0 to 4,294,967,295 (if unsigned) or from -2147483648 to +2147483647 (if signed). But it looks like holding -2147483648 to 4,294,967,295. How is it possible?

Comment: A warning is not a compilation error, but overflowing a signed type is UB in C, use a larger type (`long long`)

Comment: Note: `4294967295` has same _value_ as 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Not UB here, but the conversion is implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @chux true, implementation defined!

Comment: BTW, this is not "negative of a long int", but "negative of a long long".

Comment: I'd expect a warning in both cases.  Inconsistent compiler implementation, IMO.

Comment: You can inspect the values of `LONG_MAX` and `LONG_MIN` from a `<limits.h>` header, to see the exact limits of your `long` type implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has implementation defined behavior in both cases because the expression has type `long long int` on your 32-bit system and exceeds the range of type `long`.

The C Standard is clear about this:

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> 2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.
> 3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

The confusion may come from the `L` suffix that does not force the type of the constant, but makes it at least as large as `long int`. It would be helpful if the compiler would flag such confusing side effects, but such diagnostics are not mandated by the C Standard.

Here is a program to illustrate this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define typeof(X)  _Generic((X),                                        \
                   long double: "long double",                          \
                   double: "double",                                    \
                   float: "float",                                      \
                   unsigned long long int: "unsigned long long int",    \
                   long long int: "long long int",                      \
                   unsigned long int: "unsigned long int",              \
                   long int: "long int",                                \
                   unsigned int: "unsigned int",                        \
                   int: "int",                                          \
                   unsigned short: "unsigned short",                    \
                   short: "short",                                      \
                   unsigned char: "unsigned char",                      \
                   signed char: "signed char",                          \
                   char: "char",                                        \
                   bool: "bool",                                        \
                   default: "other")

int main() {
#define TEST(x)  printf("%8s has type %s and size %zu\n", #x, typeof(x), sizeof(x))
    TEST(4294967295);
    TEST(4294967295U);
    TEST(4294967295L);
    TEST(4294967295UL);
    TEST(4294967295LL);
    TEST(4294967295ULL);
    TEST(0xffffffff);
    TEST(0xffffffffU);
    TEST(0xffffffffL);
    TEST(0xffffffffUL);
    TEST(0xffffffffLL);
    TEST(0xffffffffULL);
    TEST(2147483647);
    TEST(2147483648);
    TEST(2147483647+1);
    TEST(-2147483647);
    TEST(-2147483648);
    TEST(-2147483647-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output on a 32-bit system (with 32-bit `int` and `long`):

```
4294967295 has type long long int and size 8
4294967295U has type unsigned int and size 4
4294967295L has type long long int and size 8
4294967295UL has type unsigned long int and size 4
4294967295LL has type long long int and size 8
4294967295ULL has type unsigned long long int and size 8
0xffffffff has type unsigned int and size 4
0xffffffffU has type unsigned int and size 4
0xffffffffL has type unsigned long int and size 4
0xffffffffUL has type unsigned long int and size 4
0xffffffffLL has type long long int and size 8
0xffffffffULL has type unsigned long long int and size 8
2147483647 has type int and size 4
2147483648 has type long long int and size 8
2147483647+1 has type int and size 4
-2147483647 has type int and size 4
-2147483648 has type long long int and size 8
-2147483647-1 has type int and size 4
```

Comment: The new colorizer is so broken: some of the integer suffixes are not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your insights. This is what I figured out.

The long variable holds values from -2147483648 to +2147483647. So it uses 32 bits (4 bytes). The statement "long universe_of_defects = 4294967295L;" does not show any warning message during compilation, and stores binary value as below.

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111

In two's complement, it is interpreted as -1. So output of following code is :

```
long universe_of_defects = 4294967295L;
printf("The entire universe has %ld bugs.\n",universe_of_defects);


The entire universe has -1 bugs.
```

Comment: Note that the suffix `L` does not mean “`long`”; it means “at least `long`.” Also, the fact that the bits for 4,294,967,295 are 11111111111111111111111111111111 and the bits for two’s complement −1 are also 11111111111111111111111111111111 does not mean that assigning a `long long` 4,294,967,295 to a 32-bit `long` will produce −1, even if the C implementation uses two’s complement. This is because the C standard does define a conversion to signed to wrap modulo 2^n but says it is implementation-defined, so the C implementation may choose (and document) what to do.

Comment: ok. So it's totally dependent on implementation of C in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

The value `4294967295L` is represented, as 64bit int two's complement as binary `0000_0000_0000_0000_1111_1111_1111_1111`, but as a 32 bit integer has no representation (32 bit integers go from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`) so the conversion to 32bit signed integer will **always result in *implementation defined behaviour*.**  The value `-4294967295L` in 64bit signed two's complement is `1111_1111_1111_1111_0000_0000_0000_0001`, and this can be the reason that, when *"converting"* it to 32bit (by truncating the 32 most significative bits),  the final value results in a positive number `+1`  (the truncation results in the pattern `0000_0000_0000_0001` or `+1`)  and this could explain the warning message you get from the compiler (you have lost the sign bit in the conversion, in this case, but in the case the compiler would have moved the 63th bit to position 31, the result would be `1000_0000_0000_0001` which is `-2147483647` in two's complement, and has nothing to do with the original value you used in the source code)

You must write portable code, and use values that can be converted between the types you are using.  The compiler is just doing its job telling you what has happened in the conversion.

Comment: **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers** *When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.*